# Headphones not recognized when plugged in to the case

Tags: headphones

I'm quite new to Linux, but I want to use as my main OS, but I'm still facing an issue.

I have a SennHeiser headphone, which works when it's plugged in the AUX IN port under Windows.

Note, this is a port which is on the case itself, not on the motherboard.
It's located next to the microphone and 2 USB 3.0 ports.

The Mic & Headphone is not working, the 2 USB ports are.

Ubuntu doesn't recognize my Headphone, so I can't select them as the output device in my settings.

Seems like I'm missing a driver.

What should I do in order to make my headphones working?

PS. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Kind regards